# FromJSON instance for newtype HashMap key

Tags: haskell, typeclass, aeson

I made a newtype `UUID` in my application to represent `Text` ids.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

...

newtype UUID =
    UUID Text
      deriving (Eq, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, FromField, ToField, FromText, Show, Read, Hashable)
```

My application needs an instance of `FromJSON` for `HashMap UUID a`. HashMap defines an instance for `HashMap Text a`, is there a way to use it when defining mine?

If I have to redefine the instance, how would I write it? Here's the equivalent from [`Data.Aeson.Types.Instances`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.10.0.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-Instances.html):

```
instance (FromJSON v) => FromJSON (H.HashMap Text v) where
    parseJSON = withObject "HashMap Text a" $ H.traverseWithKey (\k v -> parseJSON v <?> Key k)
```

How would you write this for `UUID`? Where are `Key` and `<?>` defined, and how can I look that up easily on my own? Hoogle didn't seem to help.

Comment: It looks like <?> is defined in `Data.Aeson.Types.Internal`, but I had to clone the repository to find it. Is there a better way? Also, that isn't exposed so I can't even use it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `UUID` is a newtype so you have

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Coerce
-- other imports...

instance (FromJSON v) => FromJSON (HashMap UUID v) where
  parseJSON = coerce (parseJSON :: Value -> Parser (HashMap Text v))
```

Or, perhaps the simpler way

```
  parseJSON = fmap (fromList . map (\(x,y) -> (UUID x,y)) . toList) . parseJSON
```

Which simply parses the Text HashMap, then converts it to one indexed on UUID. However, the `coerce` version is better since it has no runtime cost.

Comment: Another option is to copy the source code of the `FromJSON (HashMap Text a)` instance, which I believe is pretty short and simple. I think `aeson` made a big mistake by making its `Object` a type synonym for `HashMap Text Value`; if not for that (IMO) misjudgement, they could have offered a much nicer `instance (FromJSON v, FromJSON k, Hashable k) => FromJSON (HashMap k v)`.

Comment: Sounds like a PR is in order!

Comment: @dfeuer The current instance for `Text` uses the name of the type: `withObject "HashMap Text a"` so you would also need a `Typeable k` constraint or the like, I believe.

Comment: @user2407038 I guess it's a problem (with `type Object = HashMap Text Value`) because the authors want to leave an `Object` value alone. With a hypothetical `newtype Object = Object (HashMap Text Value)`, that could be accomplished without precluding the general instance.